# Random access textbooks

Tags: books

I'm writing a series of study guides for a programming class I'm supporting.  The study guides are broken into three main sections: concepts (syntax, mainly, as well as common things to do), skills (using multiple concepts to achieve common or useful tasks), and applications (applying skills to an open-ended problem).

The study guides are going well, but I feel that a lot of this work has already been done, or that there are templates I can be using to make things more effective.  What I am looking for is a type of resource that fits the following criteria, if it exists:

I'd like to present the students with a framing problem in high level language.  I want to go through my design process.  At each stage, I want to have links to relevant sections of the study guide/relevant practice problems.  I want an effective way to organize these links so that students are not overwhelmed by having a deluge of meandering problems to follow through before progressing through the main problem.

Does such a thing exist?  If so, what's it called, and where can I find advice about writing them?  Alternatively, if they are common and available for multiple courses, I'm happy to not re-invent the wheel and just use something already made.

**Edit**: I'm aware that what I'm describing is technically just a web page.  I'm looking for best practices for its design, rather than a technology to do it.

Comment: It somewhat sounds like you're describing a wiki.

Comment: That's a good point, actually